# Record sound and play simultaneously in iphone SDKs programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How to record sound and play simultaneously in iphone SDKs programmatically? If anybody have links and source code then please help me. Thank You very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this sample from Apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html

It should get you started.